# Suggesting options from two List<string> objects separated by a comma in C#

Tags: c#, json, autosuggest

I have an AutoSuggestBox in my application. It suggests city names from a List object, which is deserialized from a json file. I also have another List object that contains the country names. What I want to do is suggesting the options in city_name,country_name format. How do I do this?

Comment: @DourHighArch Oh, I missed some words. Check again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose there is a way to pass something like `DisplayValue` on your AutoSuggestBox which must point to a property in your class. Let's say:

```
List<MyObject> list = new List<MyObject>(); // Simulate already deserialzied list
myAutoSuggestBox.ItemsSource = list;
myAutoSuggestBox.DisplayValue = "Combined";



public class MyObject
{
     public string City { get;set; }
     public string Country { get;set; }
     public string Combined 
     {
          get
          {
              return $"{City}, {Country}";
          }
     }
}
```

P.S. I don't know if it's a desktop or web application, but that's the main idea with a desktop app.

Comment: The approach is almost the same, you just need a way to combine your two lists into one object and use the code above.

Comment: Thanks. It worked partially. If I have to access the individual member of the variable(let's say Country), how to do it?

Comment: Well, it's going to be like that: `MyObject obj = new MyObject(); obj.Country = "USA"; `